# innerHTML doesnt change span content

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

So I have got a list of items and when that number input changes, i want to change content of span but innerHTML doesn't work for me, have no idea why.

Here is the function i've got, one of the span and the number input. Someone can tell me why?

```
function miktaryenile(veri){
    var fiyati='fiyat'+veri;
    var mfiyat=document.getElementById(fiyati);
    mfiyat.innerHTML='text';
}
<span id="fiyatE-1">55</span>
<input type="number" value="1" id="E-1" onChange="miktaryenile('E-1')"></input>
```

Comment: The content of the span changes when I run your code: http://jsbin.com/risilolufe/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Use single quote in JavaScript

Comment: Quentin. Thanks i will take a look at other parts. Tbh still no idea where to look.
And Sarjan Desai i dont get whats with the quotes here.

Comment: `var fiyati="fiyat"+veri;` Use `single quote` instead of `double quote` for best practices

Comment: I solved it and got nothing to do with quotes. Just noticed i forgot a hidden input element with same id. Thanks and sorry.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the javascript code is not contained in a `<script>` tag.

Then, in javascript, `onchange` occurs when the element loses focus. If you want to monitor the change immediately after it occurred, you can use `oninput`. Note that these properties don't have a capital letter.

What's more, your input doesn't need a closing tag in HTML5.
You can see the code in action here: https://jsfiddle.net/gvhyu06s/3/

The content of the span changes to "text" when the value in the input is changed.

Comment: I wrote as a comment that i just saw i forgot a hidden input element with same id as my span, that was the problem. But that onchange will really help me. Thanks. and btw is there anything i should do to make this question unanswerable or something. I mean like closing the topic. Sorry i am new here.

Comment: If a comment helped you solve your problem and is a valid answer, you can mark it as such by clicking the tick underneath the rating. I don't think you can close the question, but if you feel it's really bad you could probably delete it completely.